# LEFT OUTER JOIN on multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to link two tables in order?

Table A (Actual):

```
EX  STATUS  DLV     Actual FEE    Expected Fee
N    ACT    MAIL    1.25
N    ACT    EMAIL   1.25
N    ACT    PICKUP  0
N    NON    MAIL    0
N    NON    EMAIL   1.25
N    NON    PICKUP  0
Y                   0
```

Table B (Expected):

```
EX  STATUS  DLV     Expected FEE
N    ACT    MAIL    1.25
N    ACT    EMAIL   0
N    ACT    PICKUP  0
N    NON    MAIL    1.25
N    NON    EMAIL   0
N    NON    PICKUP  0
Y                   0
```

Table A (Expected Result):

```
EX  STATUS  DLV     Actual FEE    Expected Fee
N    ACT    MAIL    1.25          1.25
N    ACT    EMAIL   1.25          0
N    ACT    PICKUP  0             0
N    NON    MAIL    0             1.25
N    NON    EMAIL   1.25          0
N    NON    PICKUP  0             0
Y                   0             0
```

I want to incorporate the follow logic within the join:
A.EX = B.EX (join on first)

but then on the combination of the other 3, since they are unique.

I tried this but of course it didn't work:

```
FROM
dbo.claims a
left outer join dbo.pricing p on a.EX = p.EX 
and a.STATUS = p.STATUS
and a.DLV = p.DLV
```

I was hoping to link table B to table A to get the expected fee.
If Ex = Y, then it's 0 regardless of status or DLV.  If Ex=N, then I have to depend on the other two columns.

I'm sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: If EX=Y then Fee=0, If Ex=N and Status=ACT and DLV=Mail then Fee=1.25 and so on.  I want EX to take precedence if that's possible.

Comment: Is there duplicate values on tableB? How do you expect to join both and get a single value?

Comment: Thanks.  That didn't work.  I don't think I'm explaining myself well. Basically I want to do a vlookup from table B (expected result) to table A using the first three columns to identify the expected fee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> create table tableA (EX char(1), STATUS char(3), DLV varchar(10), Actual_FEE decimal(18,2));
> insert into tableA values
> ('N', 'ACT', 'MAIL',   1.25),
> ('N', 'ACT', 'EMAIL',  1.25),
> ('N', 'ACT', 'PICKUP', 0),
> ('N', 'NON', 'MAIL',   0),
> ('N', 'NON', 'EMAIL',  1.25),
> ('N', 'NON', 'PICKUP', 0),
> ('Y', null,  null,     0);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> create table tableB (EX char(1), STATUS char(3), DLV varchar(10), Expected_FEE decimal(18,2));
> insert into tableB values
> ('N', 'ACT', 'MAIL',   1.25),
> ('N', 'ACT', 'EMAIL',  0),
> ('N', 'ACT', 'PICKUP', 0),
> ('N', 'NON', 'MAIL',   1.25),
> ('N', 'NON', 'EMAIL',  0),
> ('N', 'NON', 'PICKUP', 0),
> ('Y', null,  null,     0);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

According to your expected result it could be:

> ```
> select    a.EX, a.STATUS, a.DLV, a.Actual_FEE, b.Expected_FEE
> from      tableA a
> left join (select distinct EX, STATUS, DLV, Expected_Fee
>            from   tableB) b
> on        a.EX = b.EX
> and       (a.STATUS = b.STATUS OR b.STATUS IS NULL)
> and       (a.DLV = b.DLV or b.DLV IS NULL)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EX | STATUS | DLV    | Actual_FEE | Expected_FEE
> :- | :----- | :----- | :--------- | :-----------
> N  | ACT    | MAIL   | 1.25       | 1.25        
> N  | ACT    | EMAIL  | 1.25       | 0.00        
> N  | ACT    | PICKUP | 0.00       | 0.00        
> N  | NON    | MAIL   | 0.00       | 1.25        
> N  | NON    | EMAIL  | 1.25       | 0.00        
> N  | NON    | PICKUP | 0.00       | 0.00        
> Y  | null   | null   | 0.00       | 0.00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f8e4c17c9485ebaa57995de536d1cc36)*

Comment: Why do you have 'distinct' in your left join? Doesn't the fact that you've specified other columns removed the 'distinct'ness action? You get all of them? I've tried the fiddle with and without the embedded select distinct and the results are the same.

Answer (score 4):

If both tables consistently have null in `STATUS` and `DLV` when `EX` contains a `Y`, then you can match the two columns sets using EXISTS and INTERSECT:

```
FROM
  dbo.claims AS a
  LEFT JOIN dbo.pricing AS p
    ON EXISTS
      (
        SELECT a.EX, a.STATUS, a.DLV
        INTERSECT
        SELECT p.EX, p.STATUS, p.DLV
      )
```

What is happening there is you are matching the two column sets as rows using FROM-less SELECTs and the INTERSECT operator, rather than matching separately each column against its counterpart using the `=` operator. The difference is that in this case two nulls are considered to be equal to each other. (When comparing them using `=`, they are not.)

So, as I said, if you consistently store the `Y` rows as `'Y', NULL, NULL` in both tables, the simple rewrite above will let you match those rows when both tables have them.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to McNets +1 (I tried some other stuff)

```
declare @tableA table (EX char(1) not null, STATUS char(3), DLV varchar(10), Actual_FEE decimal(18,2));
insert into @tableA values
('N', 'ACT', 'MAIL',   1.25),
('N', 'ACT', 'EMAIL',  1.25),
('N', 'ACT', 'PICKUP', 0),
('N', 'NON', 'MAIL',   0),
('N', 'NON', 'EMAIL',  1.25),
('N', 'NON', 'PICKUP', 0),
('Y', null,  null,     0); 

declare @tableB table (EX char(1) not null, STATUS char(3), DLV varchar(10), Expected_FEE decimal(18,2));
insert into @tableB values
('N', 'ACT', 'MAIL',   1.25),
('N', 'ACT', 'EMAIL',  0),
('N', 'ACT', 'PICKUP', 0),
('N', 'NON', 'MAIL',   1.25),
('N', 'NON', 'EMAIL',  0),
('N', 'NON', 'PICKUP', 0),
('Y', null,  null,     0);

select a.EX, a.STATUS, a.DLV, a.Actual_FEE, b.Expected_FEE  
from @tableA a 
join @tableB b
  on a.EX = b.EX 
 and (   (a.STATUS = b.STATUS and a.DLV = b.DLV) 
      or (a.STATUS is null)
     )
order by a.EX, a.STATUS, a.DLV;
```

If you can live with '' this gets easy

```
declare @tableA table (EX char(1) not null, STATUS char(3), DLV varchar(10), Actual_FEE decimal(18,2)
                       primary key (ex, status, dlv));
insert into @tableA values
('N', 'ACT', 'MAIL',   1.25),
('N', 'ACT', 'EMAIL',  1.25),
('N', 'ACT', 'PICKUP', 0),
('N', 'NON', 'MAIL',   0),
('N', 'NON', 'EMAIL',  1.25),
('N', 'NON', 'PICKUP', 0),
('Y', '',    '',       0); 

declare @tableB table (EX char(1) not null, STATUS char(3), DLV varchar(10), Expected_FEE decimal(18,2)
                       primary key (ex, status, dlv));
insert into @tableB values
('N', 'ACT', 'MAIL',   1.25),
('N', 'ACT', 'EMAIL',  0),
('N', 'ACT', 'PICKUP', 0),
('N', 'NON', 'MAIL',   1.25),
('N', 'NON', 'EMAIL',  0),
('N', 'NON', 'PICKUP', 0),
('Y', '',    '',       0);

select a.EX, a.STATUS, a.DLV, a.Actual_FEE, b.Expected_FEE  
from @tableA a 
join @tableB b
  on a.EX     = b.EX 
 and a.STATUS = b.STATUS 
 and a.DLV    = b.DLV
order by a.EX, a.STATUS, a.DLV;
```